# Elasticsearch Nest Getting and updating a single Document

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I would like to be able to select a single document here is a sample of how a document looks

```
    {
    "_index": "myindex_products",
    "_type": "product",
    "_id": "8Wct9mEBlkDZwzEMRfbG",
"_version": 1,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"productId": 5749,
"name": "Product Name Here",
"productCode": "PRODCODE",
"productCategoryId": 73,
"length": 6,
"height": 0,
"productTypeId": 1,
"url": "product-name-here",
"productBrandId": 7,
"width": 0,
"dispatchTimeInDays": 10,
"leadTimeInDays": 6,
"stockAvailable": 0,
"weightKg": 0.001,
"reviewRating": 5,
"reviewRatingCount": 17,
"limitedStock": false,
"price": 16.3,
"productImage": "28796-14654.jpg",
"productCategory": {
"productCategoryId": 73,
"name": "Accessories - New",
"fullPath": "Accessories - New",
"code": "00057"
},
"productSpecification": [
{
"productSpecificationId": 127151,
"productId": 5749,
"specificationId": 232,
"name": "Brand",
"value": "Brand1"
}
,
{
"productSpecificationId": 127175,
"productId": 5749,
"specificationId": 10,
"name": "Guarantee",
"value": "10 years"
}
]
}
}
```

_id is being generated when I index so I don't know this at the point I want to update. I have the productId value and I would like to use this to select a document to then update/delete is there a way to return a single document if you know a particular exact value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While indexing, you can use something like `PUT your_index/5749` (5749 being your product id) and ES will use its value for the _id field instead of auto-generating it.

Comment: Thanks very useful